# mysqli prepeare on array?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing my own library for querying database and I want to encapsulate `mysqli_prepeare()` and `mysqli_bind` methods, but I want to write a generic method with dynamic number of parameters. With that I mean you can pass to it for example:

```
array("is", $integerId, $stringName).
```

The only solution I have found is:

```
function prepeare($notEscapedSql, $attrs)
{
    $query = mysqli_prepare($this->dbConn, $notEscapedSql);

    $ref = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt'); 
    $method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param"); 
    $method->invokeArgs($query,$attrs); 

}
```

But it is not working for me, did not really spent too much time on debuging because it is not the elegant way of solving this problem since it uses Reflection which is not supported on earlier versions of php. Are there any sollutions or suggestions?

Comment: What is `$ref_arr` here? An array with references in it? or without?

Comment: sry typo... i fixed it

Comment: How is the function being used? You would probably need to pass in attrs by reference because bind_param expects a reference.

Comment: i tried but it doesnt change a lot...

Comment: Don't forget, the first argument for `->bind_param()` is the type string.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you use the *Reflection* class to do this and why you didn't use `$query` which returns a [`mysqli_stmt`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php) object.

Moreover, `invokeArgs` as well as `call_user_func_array` take an array as second parameter. So, it is best to use the typehint `array` on your second parameter in the function `prepeare`.

You can use the `call_user_func_array`:

```
function prepeare($notEscapedSql, array $attrs)
{
    $mysqli_stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->dbConn, $notEscapedSql);
    call_user_func_array(array($mysqli_stmt, "bind_param"), $attrs);
    return $mysqli_stmt;
}
```

Comment: to be honest I forgot the call_user_func_array function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason not to use call_user_func_array is that it's slow. Reflection is newer, but it's faster. Calling bind_param dynamically is kind of painful- but there's a lot of examples in the comments which can pull you through--

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Basically, you need to do this kind of thing:

```
//arrays
$paramList = some array of parameters.
$binderList = array();
$tmpList = array();

//reflection
$ref = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt'); 
$method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");

    //loop through and perform pointer arithmetic. I know, this is horrible
    for($i=0; $i<$numParams; $i++) {
    $tmp = $paramList[$i];
    $tmpList[] = $tmp;
    $binderList[] = &$tmpList[$i]
    }

//invoke the bind_param dynamically and execute.
$method->invokeArgs($res,$binderList);   
$res->execute();
```